# introJS(): dontShowAgain option is not showing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, intro.js

These are included in my `<head>`:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/intro.js/minified/introjs.min.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/intro.js/minified/intro.min.js"></script>
```

In my javascript, I have implemented this code:

```
introJs().onexit(function() {
     document.getElementById("subdiv").scrollTo({
         top: 0,
         behavior: 'smooth'
     });
}).setOptions("dontShowAgain", true).start();
```

The tutorial animation shows, but for some reason the `Don't show again` option doesn't show. As a result the tutorial keeps opening everytime I run the page. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a small mistake in your code. The **setOptions** method takes an object as an argument, not a key and a value separately. Here's how you can fix it:

```js
introJs().onexit(function() {
     document.getElementById("subdiv").scrollTo({
         top: 0,
         behavior: 'smooth'
     });
}).setOption("dontShowAgain", false).start();
```

Notice the change in **setOptions** where **{ dontShowAgain: true }** is passed as an object.

This should resolve the issue, and the "Don't show again" option should work as expected.

Comment: I tried it, still not showing

Comment: Try to change your code as below mentioned

introJs().onexit(function() {
     document.getElementById("subdiv").scrollTo({
         top: 0,
         behavior: 'smooth'
     });
}).setOption("dontShowAgain", true).start();

Comment: If you are configuring multiple options, use "setOptions"; otherwise, use "setOption".

Comment: To display the "Don't show again" checkbox in the tour
Default: false